# If you recompile the kernel, what do you do with future updates?

Tags: system-installation, kernel

Let's say I install Ubuntu on the surface pro 3 and recompile to workaround bugs. Would I have to keep recompiling the kernel every time I install updates or even LTS updates?

Comment: Why do you need to recompile kernel?

Comment: Ah okay, that is out of my skill right now. I was thinking of transitioning a surface pro 3/MacBook air 2011 to Ubuntu but from the research I have done, it would have to be done through recompiling the kernel. Not everything works right out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile a kernel that is newer and therefore has a higher release number than the current Ubuntu kernel (for example `4.6.6`) you don't have to do anything at all, because the system will just keep on booting that kernel, and you can upgrade all other packages as normal (`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`). You may have some compatibility issues of course.

If a new Ubuntu release arrives, then there will be a jump to a new kernel series, and if the new Ubuntu kernel has a higher version number than yours, then the newer Ubuntu kernel will be booted by default, so you would have to either pin your kernel or use a newer one.

If you're recompiling the Ubuntu kernel to patch it, you'd either have to recompile each time a kernel upgrade arrives (which is pretty regularly), or you could pin or just keep choosing your compiled version by configuring GRUB until you could be bothered to recompile.

This way has the advantage of allowing you to check whether the new kernel works for you unpatched. I used to used a custom kernel, but now I don't have to because the bugs got squashed in newer kernels.

Comment: If you use a custom kernel, the easiest way is to remove Ubuntu kernel with meta package.

Comment: You can leave one Ubuntu kernel as a backup, and delete just meta: `linux-image-generic`, `linux-headers-generic`.

Comment: Is the kernel with the higher release the unstable or developer version?

Comment: When I say higher release I mean `4.7.1` is higher than `4.4.0-34` which is higher than `3.19.0-56`. The system boots the highest release by default. @studentofarkad or am I not understanding you? Only mainline kernel (for testing) is unstable (in theory(!)) [see here for what I mean](https://www.kernel.org/). Currently Ubuntu 16.04 uses kernels from the series `4.4`

Comment: Yeah I was just confused as to why Ubuntu 16.04 will have different kernel version. My assumption was that new versions would come subsequently with higher releases of the kernel.

Comment: they do @studentofarkad , but Ubuntu kernel development moves fairly conservatively through releases, and is always a few numbers behind the newest vanilla kernel

Comment: @Zanna Okay, that makes a lot more sense, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can remove meta packages by this command

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-generic linux-headers-generic
```

and Ubuntu kernels will never get updates.

This command will not remove kernels, you can keep Ubuntu kernel(s) in case something goes wrong with your custom kernel.

With LTS releases kernel meta packages may have other names. For example Ubuntu 16.04.2 will have `linux-image-generic-lts-yakkety`.